# How do I create a hash of hashes from Spreadsheet::ParseExcel data?

Tags: perl

I am working with the [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) module. I want to create a hash of hash with the Excel data:

```
{
    'P343453' => {
        'Date'   => 03022011,
        'Method' => 'No',
        'Time'   => 1440,
    },
    'P343763' => {
        'Date'   => 03022011,
        'Method' => 'YES',
        'Time'   => '1745',
    }
}
```

What I have now is something like this:

```
{
    'P343453' => [
        '03022011',
        'No',
        '1440',
    ],
    'P343763' => [
        '03022011',
        'YES',
        '1745',
    ],
}
```

Here is my code:

```
my @worksheets = $workbook->worksheets();
warn "More than 1 worksheet found\n" if @worksheets > 1;

# Only work with first page.
my $worksheet = $worksheets[0];

my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
my @required_col = (1 .. $col_max);
my @value;

##to get the headers of the excel file;
for my $row ( 0 .. 0 ) {
    @value = map {
        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, $_);
        $cell ? $cell->value() : '';
    } @required_col;
}

# Skip header row
my $sample_details = {};
for my $row (1  .. $row_max ) {
    my @data = map {
        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, $_);
        $cell ? $cell->value() : '';
    } @required_col;
    $sample_details->{$worksheet->get_cell($row,0)->value()} = \@data
        if defined $worksheet->get_cell($row, 0)->value();
}
```

How should I modify the code to assign the keys to the hashrefs of the hash from the array `@value`?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean the [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) module?

Comment: Yes. Its Spreadsheet::ParseExcel .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Skip header row
my $sample_details = {};
for my $row (1  .. $row_max ) {
  my  @data = map {
        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, $_);
        $cell ? $cell->value() : '';
    } @required_col;

  foreach my $col (@values) {
    $sample_details->{$worksheet->get_cell($row,0)->value()}{$col} = shift @data  if defined $worksheet->get_cell($row, 0)->value();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was dump not to have tried with shift ! two foreach loop with in each other ! I was going crazy ! Thanks Perreal

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `\@data` in the last line with this:

```
  { map { ($value[$_] => $data[$_]) } (0..$#value) }
```

This will make a key/value pair from each list value using the corresponding header as key.